# How can you limit the columns PHPExcel reads?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a large excel file (two worksheets of ~4000 rows and columns out to AF). The excel table is formatted terribly, and I have no control over it. There are hundreds of blank columns going all the way out to XFC.

How can I have PHPExcel choose which columns it reads/writes based on the code, below? I tried using what the documentation said, but it obviously isn't working.

Code:

```
<?php 

require('./Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');


ini_set('max_execution_time', 800);
ini_set('memory_limit', 200M);  

$inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
$inputFileName = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'];

//٧٧ this is what documentation suggested ٧٧//
class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter {     
    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
          // Read columns from 'A' to 'AF'
          if ($column >= '0' && $column <= '32'){
              return true;
          }
          return false;
      }
}
//^^this is what documentation suggested^^//

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

$loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetNames();

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelReader, 'CSV');

foreach($loadedSheetNames as $sheetIndex => $loadedSheetName) {
                          $objWriter->setSheetIndex($sheetIndex);
                          $objWriter->save('abc.csv');}

$files = fopen('abc.csv', 'r'); 
    while (($line = fgetcsv($files)) !== FALSE) {
    $csv_array[] = array_combine(range(1, count($line)), array_values($line));
    }

?>
```

Comment: Where is your filter used?

Comment: I run the filter beginning on Line 8. It now has been marked with the note "// this is what documentation suggested //"

Comment: See @MarkBaker answer, you only declare the filter, but never instantiate it, how can it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply creating a class isn't enough: you need to tell PHPExcel to actually use your `MyReadFilter` class

```
/**  Create an Instance of the Read Filter  **/ 
$filterSubset = new MyReadFilter(); 

/**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/ 
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType); 
/**  Tell the Reader that we want to use the Read Filter  **/ 
$objReader->setReadFilter($filterSubset); 
/**  Load only the rows and columns that match our filter to PHPExcel  **/ 
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
```

See section 5.3 - `Reading Only Specific Columns and Rows from a File (Read Filters)` - of the `PHPExcel User Documentation - Reading Spreadsheet Files` document

**EDIT**

If you're working with columns, then you need to work with column letters, because the column id passed into the readfilter is a column ID, not a column number

**Either** convert to a number (inefficient if you do it in `readCell()`):

```
class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter {
    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
          // Read columns from 'A' to 'AF'
          if (PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($column) -1 >= 0) &&
              PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($column) -1 <= 32) {
              return true;
          }
          return false;
      }
}
```

**or** compare as a column ID

```
class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter {

    public function __construct($fromColumn, $toColumn) {
        $this->columns = array();
        $toColumn++;
        while ($fromColumn !== $toColumn) {
            $this->columns[] = $fromColumn++;
        }
    }

    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
          // Read columns from 'A' to 'AF'
          if (in_array($column, $this->columns)) {
              return true;
          }
          return false;
      }
}
```

and instantiate the read filter using:

```
$filterSubset = new MyReadFilter('A', 'AF');
```

Comment: Okay, I believe this fixed my issue. The code runs in a fractionof the time it used to. I watch the saved file size go up to around 200mB (expected), but then it jumps down to 3B and has nothing in any of its cells. Any idea why this may happen?

Comment: If you're working with columns, then you need towork with column letters, because the column id passed into the readfilter is a column ID, not a column number

Comment: Changed, however this does not address the issue of missing data. Would it be more appropriate for me to make a new question? I think it has something to do with my code loading sheet names. I think it is overwriting the old sheets, not saving them as seperate sheets as it is meant to.

Comment: btw, missing a `{` on the `while` function beginning on `Line 6` of the `compare as column ID` section of your answer

Comment: Thanks, that'll teach me to write an answer without actually testing it